# How do I solve this inequality? $\sin x < 2x^3$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

The equation is

$\sin x < 2x^3$

The steps I've taken so far are:

$\sin x < 2x^3 $

$\sin x  - 2x^3 < 0 $

To solve this I should find when the slope is $ 0 $ so I can find the max and min points and determine the direction of the equation.

$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x  - \frac{d}{dx}2x^3 < 0 \ $

$\cos x  - 6x^2 < 0 \ $

The max and mins are found when $\cos x  = 6x^2 $

I'm not sure how I can solve this last part since I can't take arccos of $ 6x^2 $

Comment: Try graphing both sides for intuition.

Comment: I have graphed this, and quite honestly, graphing is the solution written in the book; I would like to go beyond that however. I don't like to rely on technology for answers. I would prefer to solve it algebraically.

Comment: I know you said you do like technology. But Mathematica says this: `N@Reduce[Sin[x] < 2 x^3, x]` answer : `-0.679964 < x < 0. || x > 0.679964`

Comment: Well thank you, but I'm not looking for an answer; I'm looking for a method.

Comment: On what domain this inequality holds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Introduction

To entirely clarify the situation for the OP, I will first explain a general method for solving inequalities, followed by a brief explanation of Newton's Method.

### General method of solving inequalities

To find the region satisfied by an inequality, we can first find the points which will definitely **not** be satisfied by the inequality.

To explain this, I will demonstrate using an example which can be solved explicitly without resorting to numerical methods. Once we understand the basic process of solving inequalities using points, we can learn how to find the points with numerical methods.

Suppose we have the inequality

$$
x^2 < 4
$$

This means that whenever $x^2=4$, the inequality is not true. In fact, the solutions for $x^2 = 4$ form the boundaries for the region satisfied by the inequality. Solving the equation $x^2 = 4$ for $x$, we obtain $x=\pm 2$.

Plotting these points on a number line, we see the following:

[image: $x^2=4$]

Because these are the boundaries for $x^2 < 4$, we must use open circles, rather than closed circles to represent the points.

[image: number line for inequality]

Now we can check which regions which satisfy the inequality. The three regions are

$$
x < -2 \\
-2 < x < 2\\
x > 2\\
$$

We check each region using any point from within the region. For example,

if $x < -2$ satisfies $x^2 < 4$, then $(-3)^2 < 4$. This is not true, so we know that the region $x < -2$ is not a solution to the inequality. We do similar checks for the remaining two regions, and find that the only region which satisfies the inequality is $-2 < x < 2$.

[image: number line with inequality region]

Thus we have solved the inequality $x^2 < 4$. We know that to solve an inequality, we simply find the roots of the equivalent equality, then test the regions around each root. This can be applied to any inequality, assuming we can find the roots of the equivalent equality.

### Newton's Method

Sometimes we encounter equations for which we cannot easily find the roots. (Remember that we need to find the roots of the equivalent equality so we can find the regions for the inequality.) Newton's Method allows us to iteratively approximate the roots of a large number of functions.

Newton's Method is generally stated as follows, where $x_n$ is our first approximation for the root and $x_{n+1}$ is the slightly improved approximation from Newton's Method: (I'm stealing this from @nbubis so I don't have to type it.)

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$

To use Newton's Method, we must start with a reasonably good guess for the roots. Note that Newton's Method can only find one root at a time, and it will generally home in on the root it is closest to.

### Solution to the original question

We are trying to solve the inequality $\sin x < 2x^3$, so we must find the roots of the equivalent equality: $\sin x = 2x^3$. We can easily see that $x=0$ is a solution of the equality. Also, both $\sin x$ and $2x^3$ are symmetrical about the line $y=x$, so if x is a positive root, then the negative root -x also exists, as @nubis mentioned.

I don't quite follow @nubis' explanation that "$|x| < \sqrt[3]{1/2} \sim 0.79$". However, I think it is easy to see that when $x$ is positive, both $\sin x$ and $2x^3$ are positive in the region $0 < x < \pi$. Also, we know that $\sin x \leq 1$ at all times, while $2x^3 > 1$ when $x > 1$. Thus the positive root lies in the region $0 < x \leq 1$

Once again, we follow @nbubis' lead by approximating the root as $x = \frac{1}{2}$. (You don't have to use this approximation. The beauty of Newton's Method is that any reasonably close approximation will usually work. To get a feel for how the method works, try substituting 0.4, or 0.8 (or any number between 0 and 1) to see how it converges. You could also try something ridiculously far off, like 20, to see what happens then.)

Newton's Method states

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$

We rearrange the equation $\sin x = 2x^3$ as $\sin x - 2x^3 = 0$.

Now

$$
f(x) = \sin x - 2x^3\\
f'(x) = \cos x - 6x^2\\
$$

and our first approximation of the root is $x_0 = 0.5$. So

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\\
&= x_n - \frac{\sin x - 2x^3}{\cos x - 6x^2}\\
x_1&= 0.5 - \frac{f(0.5)}{f'(0.5)}\\
&= 0.5 - \frac{\sin (0.5) - 2(0.5)^3}{\cos (0.5) - 6(0.5)^2}\\
&= 0.8686039699
\end{align}
$$

Substituting $x_1$ back into Newton's Method as our new approximation ($x_n$), we obtain a closer approximation for $x_2$ and so on. As @nbubis showed,

$$
\begin{align}
x_2 &= 0.72759492\\
&...\\
x_5 &= 0.67996445\\
\end{align}
$$

You can repeat this process until you either get bored, or you decide to search $\sin x = 2x^3$ in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csin+x+%3D+2x%5E3). =P

We have now found the positive root of the equation. $x = 0.67996445$. We know from earlier arguments that the negative root is $-x$, so the negative root is $x = -0.67996445$.

We now have all the roots of the equation!

$$
\begin{align}
x &= -0.67996445\\
x &= 0\\
x &= 0.67996445\\
\end{align}
$$

These points define four regions, as shown below:

[image: number line again!]

Now we simply follow the exact steps we used before to find the regions specified by an inequality once we know the roots of the equivalent equality.

We change the closed circles of the equality to the open circles of the inequality:

[image: another number line]

Then we check each region as before, and find the result:

[image: final number line!]

$$
\begin{align}
-0.67996445 < x &< 0\\
x &> 0.67996445\\
\end{align}
$$

### Conclusion

This all looks incredibly long and arduous. However, with practice (and when you are not including every step in an explanation =P) you can probably solve this in under five minutes.

Good luck with your future mathematical endeavours.

Comment: Very nice!  We might also mention that you can type the original inequality into WolframAlpha directly, like: [sin(x)<2x^3](http://goo.gl/RWXWA).

Comment: Of course. =D But that would take all the fun out of it!

Comment: (I did type most of these things into WolframAlpha, including the original inequality so that I could get the pretty number lines.)

Comment: I guessed that's where you got the number lines from - I just figured that this might be useful information for the OP, as well. :)

Comment: Ooh! I just looked at your profile, and noticed you have actually contributed to the development of Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: To abuse the comment system further, may I suggest that [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com) is a better (free) alternative hosting solution than Google Sites? You mention on your website that you are switching to Google sites, but I think you will probably get a better experience with the GitHub version.

Comment: Yes, I contribute math content to WolframAlpha on a part-time basis - I wrote much of the number line code, in fact. :)  My full-time gig is as a mathematics professor and the (regrettable) choice of Google Sites was made by the university. Thanks for the info, though!

Comment: Awesome answer!!! Great content and a very good contribution to the forums. It's a shame I cannot mark both as a correct answer; I've switched the correct answer to this one for the following reasons: `1.` you provide a very in depth solution to the problem `2.` you've explained Newton's Method for those that don't know it `3.` you've organized your answer with headings. Though, I don't think it is necessary to describe the general method to solve inequalities as whomever reads this particular question will likely know how to do this already, but for the sake of completeness it is nice. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

First solve for equality. This equation can really only be solved numerically, but you can note a number of things without a computer:

- $x = 0$ is a solution.
- For any solution $x$, -$x$ is also one.
- Since $\sin x < 1$, any solution must have: $|x| < \sqrt[3]{1/2} \sim 0.79$

Numerically you will find that: $$x \sim -0.68, 0, 0.68$$ So that your inequality is satisfied when:
$$x > 0.6799..$$
$$-0.6799.. < x < 0$$

**Edit:** To use Newton's method to solve $f(x) = \sin x - 2x^3 = 0$, we start with some guess value $x_0$, and the iterate:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} =  x_n - \frac{\sin x - 2x^3}{\cos x - 6x^2}$$
Say we start with $x_0 =0.5$, then the next iterations leads to:
$$x_1 = 0.86860396$$
$$x_2 = 0.72759492$$
$$x_3 = 0.68425682$$
$$x_4 = 0.68000441$$
$$x_5 = 0.67996445$$
As you can see, the more we iterate, the closer we get to the "true" result. This is what is meant by numerically - you can't find a closed expression for the solution, but you can find the numerical value.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on *how* you solved it? When you say numerically, I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd - one generally uses a computer (tabulate values in a spreadsheet, write your own code, use wolfram alpha). You could do it by hand by using Newton's method.

Comment: @daviewales - the solutions for equality, not for the inequality.

Comment: Newton's method is the normal way to evaluate something like this.

Comment: You would use Newton's methods to find the roots of $\sin x - 2x^3 = 0$, then you could test the regions defined by the roots to determine where the equation was true.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your answer.

Comment: I will delete it to prevent confusion.

Comment: @daviewales how do I do this? The important question here is *how* to solve this. I would really like to know a method besides using technology.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd - Edited my answer to address your comments.

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd, nbubis' edited answer shows how to use Newton's Method. May I ask what year you are in? I think I learnt Newton's Method in either year 11 or year 12, and again in first year university.

Comment: @daviewales I've not learned Newton's Method yet. This is a grade 12 Advanced Functions course. The method we are supposed to use is graphing, but I want to go beyond that. I've also already finished Calculus 12 and I have not seen it there either--different Curriculum I suppose.

Comment: I'm creating an answer that explains it all a bit more cohesively. If you're impatient, you can look up Newton's Method on the internet. It's a pretty simple technique.

Comment: I've added a very detailed answer which you may peruse at your leisure. If you do any calculus at uni next year, you will definitely encounter Newtons Method. Good luck with your further studies.